# métodos abstratos de mesma assinatura

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Olá, Estou construindo para meu trabalho de faculdade um WebService com base na arquitetura MVC. Para melhor entendimento do problema vou explicar um pouco como estão atualmente as classes:

- A classe abstrata Model tem como um dos métodos abstratos o `getTableName` que retorna o nome real da tabela para a model.
- Esta classe usa a trait `DML`.
- A trait `DML` depende do método `getTableName` para informar a tabela as funções de select, insert, update e delete.

Meu problema é que não é possível definir o método `getTableName` como abstrato na trait e na classe que usa a trait e não quero ficar dependente da trait `DML` para que este metodo seja abstrato.

Resumindo: Preciso que o método `getTableName` seja abstrato na trait pois ela precisa dele, mas, se a classe que usa trait também precisar que este método seja abstrato o que pode ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tanto a classe quanto a trait necessitam do mesmo método, o erro está na concepção da modelagem, uma vez que a trait é uma herança horizontal.

Você precisa avaliar o seu modelo e definir onde vai ficar e verificar porquê existe a necessidade cada uma delas ter esse mesmo método.

Se não for necessário que ambas tenham, basta definir qual deverá ser a proprietária do método.

Outra sugestão seria a implementação de uma classe base que fosse dona dessas características.